# Problem with .htaccess - RewriteRule is appending new URL to old URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm very new to htaccess and mod_rewrite things, so please forgive me the possibly stupid question :-)
I have a Links like that on my menu
teams/senioren/herren-1
teams/senioren/damen-1
etc.

and I want to redirect it to
team.php?team=herren-1
team.php?team=damen-1

My htaccess looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^teams/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ team.php?team=$2 [L,QSA]
```

That works on localhost when I click the link one time. The URL then gets https://localhost/teams/senioren/herren-1. But when I click a second time I get https://localhost/teams/senioren/teams/senioren/herren-1. So it looks like it appends the new URL to the old one.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: That is a bit surprising, since your rule does not even implement a redirection, but an internal rewrite. Are you sure that the visible URL in the browser is really changed? If so then some other logic is responsible...

Comment: Could it be that your application logic (php) sends a redirection once it has finished processing a request?

Comment: @arkascha, thanks for your fast replay :-) Well, I'm realy new to it, so perhaps I'm doing something basic wrong. I have a link to https://localhost/teams/senioren/herren-1 on my menu.php. menu.php is include in every file I have. When I click the link the content of page team.php?team=herren-1 is showen, the URL changes in Browser. On this page when I click the menu link again it appends the URL like mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, OK, now we are getting closer... Please check how that link really looks like. Not where it points to, but examine the html you hand out to the browser. You certainly know how to use your browsers development console (F12 typically) and how to examine the `<a href="...">` element in there. What is actually coded as reference? Is it a URL? Or an absolute path? Or a relative path?

Comment: Its <a href="teams/senioren/herren-1">Herren 1</a>

Comment: Ah, ok. When I code <a href="../../teams/senioren/herren-1">Herren 1</a> it works. Hm, but is that realy the right way? Or do I have to define some basic Parameters in htaccess like RewriteBase when I'm on localhost?

Comment: Yeah, correct. The issue is that you are using a _relative_ like. The browser attaches that _partial_ path to the path already loaded in the browser, which leads to the concatenation. So it indeed has nothing to do with your rewriting rule which works just fine and does no _redirection_ but only an internal _rewrite_ ...

Comment: What is typical done is that you implement your logic such that it uses an _absolute_ path, not a relative one. So something like `<a href="/teams/senioren/herren-1">`. Note: `/teams/senioren/herren-1` and `teams/senioren/herren-1` are something different, absolute versus relative. Sometimes that might require your application logic to be aware of its actual URL path. That can be determined, but usually it is easier to keep it as a configuration setting.

Comment: Hint: the "Sometimes" above refers for example to an application that should be portable, so which could be deployed under different paths which still working correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use absoluth Path like arkascha mentioned in the comments.
So in my case use /teams/senioren/herren-1 instead of teams/senioren/herren-1